# Reading different dataframes based on a variable. Is it possible?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've been tasked to making a "dating algorithm" where I use a .csv file to load all the users and from there subset it to each gender.
Currently, I make an if-statement where

```
if(user_sexuality=="female"){
    #compare females from subset
}else{
    #compare men from subset
}
```

If possible I want to remove this if-statement by using a variable instead of i.e.

```
female$age
male$age
```

This is how my code is currently set up:

```
users <- read.table("users.csv", sep=";", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
searching = read.table("searching.csv",sep=";", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
score <- read.table("score.csv",sep=";", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

male <- subset(users,gender=="male")
female <- subset(users,gender=="female")

#If we take example in user 1 who's interested in "female"
user_sexuality <- users$looking_for[1]

if(user_sexuality=="female"){
    for(i in 1:nrow(female)){
        if(female$age[i] > searching$minage[row_no] &
        female$age[i] < searching$maxage[row_no]){ 
            age_score <- score$age[1]
            age_vec <- c(aget_vec,age_score)
        }
    }
}else{
   #the exact same thing as in above but with male instead of female
}
```

When I define user_sexuality to "female" I've tried two methods neither of them working. I write the following in console:

```
>user_sexuality$age
Error in user_sexuality$age : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
>cat(paste(user_sexuality,"$age[",1,"]",sep=""))
female$age[1]
```

Whereas if I do it normally with female, I get what I am looking for:

```
>female$age[1]
[1] 19
```

Comment: `users$looking for[1]` returns the first element from the column `looking_for`, not data for user 1. The result is a vector of length 1, hence the "invalid for atomic vectors" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

I am not entirely sure why parse is required, but eval does not work on it's own.

```
female <- data.frame( age = c(1,2,3) )
user_sexuality <- "female"
i <- 1
eval(parse(text=paste0(user_sexuality,"$age[",i,"]")))
[1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solution pretty much halved the length of my code!